# Passing objects back from view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, object, initialization, segue

I have three view controllers - OneVC, TwoVC, and ThreeVC - using push segues. On OneVC, an object is created called firstObject and it's values are set when the user fills in a text field. Similar happens on TwoVC except the object created is called secondObject. The objects are passed to the next view controller via prepareForSegue().

When moving "Back" from ThreeVC -> TwoVC, the textFields remain filled in.

TwoVC -> OneVC, text fields still filled in.

What I want to fix is when going forward again from OneVC -> TwoVC, the text field in TwoVC is cleared, but I'd like it to retain what was previously filled in and set for secondBrand.someValue the first time around. I'm guessing it has something to do with how I'm initializing secondObject in TwoVC. What should I be doing here instead?

Here's my code:

Object custom class:

```
class Object {
    var someValue: String = ""
}
```

OneVC:

```
class OneVC: UIViewController {

    var firstObject: Object!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.firstObject = Object()
    }

    @IBAction func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        firstObject.someValue = textField.text!
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "OneToTwoSegue" {
            let twoVC = segue.destinationViewController as! TwoVC
            twoVC.firstObject = firstObject
        }
    }
}
```

TwoVC:

```
class TwoVC: UIViewController {

    var firstObject: Object!
    var secondObject: Object!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.secondObject = Object()
    }

    @IBAction func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
        secondObject.someValue = textField.text!
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "TwoToThreeSegue" {
            let threeVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ThreeVC
            threeVC.firstObject = firstObject
            threeVC.secondObject = secondObject
        }
    }
}
```

ThreeVC:

```
class ThreeVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstObjectLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondObjectLabel: UILabel!

    var firstObject: Object!
    var secondObject: Object!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        firstObjectLabel.text = "firstObject.someValue = \(firstObject.someValue)"
        secondObjectLabel.text = "secondObject.someValue = \(secondObject.someValue)"
    }
}
```

[Source code](https://github.com/redhurley/InitializingObjectsSample)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to pass back an object from your second ViewController back to your first ViewController before it get's deallocated and then pass it again to the second ViewController and display it in the text field.

In order to pass an object back create a delegation protocol. For example, create a file called "Protocol.swift":

```
protocol writeValueBackDelegate {
    func writeValueBack(value: String)
}
```

On your first ViewController, set your delegate when you load the second VC. Now you can save objects in your first ViewController from the second.

The final code would look something like this:

```
class Object {
    var someValue: String = ""
}
```

OneVC:

```
class OneVC: UIViewController, writeValueBackDelegate {

var firstObject: Object!
var secondObject: Object!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.firstObject = Object()
    self.secondObject = Object()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    firstObject.someValue = textField.text!
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "OneToTwoSegue" {
        let twoVC = segue.destinationViewController as! TwoVC
        //set OneVC to be a delegate for a TwoVC
        twoVC.delegate = self

        twoVC.firstObject = firstObject
        twoVC.secondObject = secondObject
    }
}

func writeValueBack(value: String) {
    // This is my value from my second View Controller
    print("first:" + value)
    self.secondObject.someValue = value
}
}
```

TwoVC:

```
class TwoVC: UIViewController {

var delegate: writeValueBackDelegate?


@IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
var firstObject: Object!
var secondObject: Object!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    inputField.text = secondObject.someValue

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    secondObject.someValue = textField.text!
    // Save the value in the delegate
    delegate?.writeValueBack(secondObject.someValue)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "TwoToThreeSegue" {
        let threeVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ThreeVC
        threeVC.firstObject = firstObject
        threeVC.secondObject = secondObject
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This works great - thank you! If you'd like to post the comments and code you added here, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: Great. I'm glad that I could help.

Comment: @D_W code is included. Let me know if that is a good answer. Thank you.